# How to convert tabular string to json using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am using node.js and I wish to format this string given below:

```
13      0.02    23      0.11    0.15    37      AIRLINES
74      0.02    343     0.08    0.23    708     ALL CLOTHING STORES
211     0.02    127     0.02    0.03    386     ALL ENTERTAINMENT
```

to the following format :

```
{[13,0.02,23,0.11,0.15,37] : AIRLINES },
{[74,0.02,343,0.08,0.23,708]: ALL CLOTHING STORES}
{[211,0.02,127,0.02,0.03,386 ]:    ALL ENTERTAINMENT}
```

Help is very much appreciated! ..

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283201/how-to-convert-tabular-string-to-json-using-nodejs/41283599#41283599) below help you? Any comments?

Comment: No , I have tried but i have not got any success.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result is not valid JSON.

If you want to convert TSV data to JSON then you can use one of:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsv
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser

Or some other module from that list:

- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/tsv

There's also this module:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tsv-json

but I'm not sure if it works because the CI badge shows failing tests.